# Remove session attribute when opening Facelets page

Tags: jsf-2, session-variables, servlet-filters

I am returning a message from servlet filter to a Facelets page. To transfer the message from servlet filter to Facelets page, I am using a session variable. After the message is displayed, I would like to remove the session variable. How this can be achieved?
Also is there an alternate way to pass data from servlet to Facelets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove it during the afterphase of `RENDER_RESPONSE`. You could use `<f:view afterPhase>` for this.

```
<f:view afterPhase="#{bean.removeSessionAttributeAfterRender}">
```

with

```
public void removeSessionAttributeAfterRender(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getSessionMap().remove("sessionAttributeName");
    }
}
```